# JInternalFrame dynamically show and hide titlebar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jinternalframe

In the beginning, my JInternalFrame's titlebar is hidden (`((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).setNorthPane(null)`). As soon as the mouse enters the frames border, I want to show the titlebar again until the border or the titlebar itself will fire a mouseExit.

This was my first trial:

```
public class InternalWindow extends JInternalFrame{
    public InternalWindow(){
        ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).setNorthPane(new BasicInternalFrameTitlePane(iw));
                ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).getNorthPane().revalidate();
                ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).getNorthPane().repaint();
                setFrameIcon(null);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
                ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).getNorthPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
                        revalidate();
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But then the titlebar isn't drawn correctly and doesn't react on interactions. [(picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94R2K.png)

So I tried it another way:

```
public class InternalWindow extends JInternalFrame{
    public InternalWindow(){
        ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                updateUI();
                setFrameIcon(null);
                ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).getNorthPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
                        revalidate();
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This way the titlebar is drawn correctly, but therefore the AWT-EventQueue throws an exception which prevents the mouseExited attached to the border to be called:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI.updateFrameCursor(BasicInternalFrameUI.java:317)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI$BorderListener.mouseEntered(BasicInternalFrameUI.java:1086)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered(AWTEventMulticaster.java:300)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6544)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4676)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4654)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4505)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Isn't there just a simple way to hide and show the titlebar dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found some kind of hack around by simply registering two separate MouseListeners for the mouseEntered and mouseExited of the border and removing that one for the mouseExited in the mouseEntered and readding it in the mouseExited of the titlebar. But I'm sure there must be a more elegant way to achieve this...

```
    MouseAdapter ma1 = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    };

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            updateUI();
            setFrameIcon(null);
            ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).getNorthPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iw.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                    addMouseListener(ma1);
                }
            });
            removeMouseListener(ma1);
        }
    });
```